# any one have a workaround in Linux for firefox's bogus "video can't be played because the file is corrupt" message

Tags: linux, firefox, vlc-media-player, mp4

Systems are Xubuntu 14.04.2, 64-bit running (currently) Firefox 37.0.2 (provided by Canonical).

attempts with firefox to open training videos by clicking on the website-provided links at (e.g.)

> http://cslbehring.wikidoc.org:8000/images/8/87/IMP_Video-SD_480p.mp4

...result in the title's bogus message about the file being corrupt.

- directly opening the link in vlc works ok
- downloading and playing the file also works (but with a significant cost of file management and time wasted)

is there a way to force firefox to "hand off" the playing of this video to vlc or the parole media player?

Comment: Have you checked if this is a flash compatibility issue? Note that under Linux there's no other way than using Googles' Chrome browser to get the newest flash.

Comment: I have a strong preference to avoid adding another piece of software to the mix when I already have two perfectly good players.  Is there no way to force firefox to treat .mp4 videos like, for example, a .pdf file, and force it to hand-off to an external viewer/player?  There are a dozen systems, and more users, involved who would have to be trained, explained and maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Somethin like [MediaPlayerConnectivity](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/mediaplayerconnectivity/) could do the trick.

Comment: really close - but not suitable for my user base.  On the page in question, it required several clicks in different places in the interface to (1) inventory all the embedded media, (2) list  the items, whose names did not match the presented names on the page, (3) actually play the movie